# How to use polynomial to describe this?

Tags: polynomials, signal-processing, data-analysis

I hava a stupid question. I would like to use a 7$^{th}$ order Polynomial to describe this figure. But if I use the matlab function $polyfit(x,y,7)$, Runge's phenomenon will come up. Currently I have no idea to solve that, anybody has good idea about that? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Consider the derivative of the function. There are two big jumps, as you can see. Is the derivative continuous in those spots? What I mean, is that I doubt that can be a pretty polynomial ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you mean, I should use the a Piecewise linear function to desrcibe that?

Comment: Perhaps. It depends on the accuracy that you want for the model. Does it need to be "inifinitely" precise?